# How to aggregate different types of Rails models into one collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let’s say I have several different types of models in my Rails application. Maybe they only have one thing in common. I want to aggregate them together into one array and sort by date. Does Rails provide some way of doing this that is more elegant/efficient than simply fetching each collection individually?

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html

Comment: @Alex Delegated Types is very close to what I am looking for. However, DT is more like a has_one polymorphic, whereas I am looking for more of a has_many that doesn’t require extra database records.

Comment: DelegatedType seems like exactly what you want, at least if I understand your question directly. You would put the timestamp/date into the `Entry` part and then query on `entries` to get your "mixed" collection.